# Enterprise Application in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, enterprise, project-structure

can you give me some hit or give me explanation how to create Enterprise App in .net, and how projects type use or how should be structure of this projects? I newbie in EE and I read about it, but for me is the best explanation on real world example. My idea about EE solution structure in .net is that:

- **Data Tier** (project type => class library)

  - database access classes
  - some mappers (I am not sure if I could use data mapper pattern or else? Is good idea?)
- **Bussiness Tier** (project type => class library)

  - entities which wil lbe mapped in data mapper in Data Tier
  - and some application logic
  - service tier (I am not sure if it should be individual tier, or subtier of                        bussiness tier - I want to use WCF)
- **Client** (project type => WebForms / Android / WPF / ....)

  - will be communicate with bussiness tier over WCF

Is my idea good? I will be gratefull for any explanation or hint how patterns could I use with respect my low knowledge. I have requirements to use 2-3 patterns, becouse is school project. Thanks for answers

Comment: Consider using Web API.

Comment: Web API is part of MVC, so is not better to use WCF for split tiers?

Answer (score 0):

For the data layer I would go with repository pattern and unit of work pattern. This is really good way to abstract data layer and create testable code which can be easily unit tested.

Business layer it depends, by DDD business should be encapsulated inside rich data model. Anemic data model is considered as anti pattern. But personally rich model can lead to the ruin of the separation of concern paradigm. Sometimes it is useful to have anemic data model and business layer on top of that model. Like handlers where every handler does exactly one action...

On top of business layer is usually application layer which expose interface to the outside, to your clients. It should be really thin without any business logic in it. Maybe Restful API which will enable you to connect various clients like Android, wpf, Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

A implementation I have found quite useful is:

- Data Access Layer:

  - Entity Framework: Unit of Work
  - Repository Pattern
- Business Layer

  - This layer maps entities and db calls to DTOs
- Presentation Layer

  - Here you present your DTOS using MV? or any other model

There you are using at least 4 design patterns.